# Bypass SSL check on java.net.URL

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm running Springboot on localhost at https://localhost:8443/ so some images would be at https://localhost:8443/image?image=path/to/file

Thing is, I need the base64 string before passing on to the template :

```java
images.add(getBase64EncodedImage("https://localhost:8443/" + strTemp));
```

```java
    public String getBase64EncodedImage(String imageURL) throws IOException {
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(imageURL);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        byte[] bytes = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
    }
```

But I get :

> PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59117386/how-fix-unsecured-jwt-set-uri-in-spring-security-oauth)

Answer (score 0):

To communicate to an SSL endpoint, the client requires the to trust the endpoint. Java has a  truststore ($JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts). The truststore contains a list of all known Certificate Authority (CA) certificates, and Java will only trust certificates that are signed by one of those CAs or public certificates that exist within that truststore.

Now in absnce of a valid certificate you have the following opions,

- to use your own `TrustManager`. However, this is not a preferable alternative.
- You could try to use the `http` instead of `https` endpoint to bypass the check.
- If you aren't able to use the http endpoint, you can try to add the required certificate in the java trust store.
  For this, you need to download the certificate from chrome and install

`keytool -import -alias example -keystore  "path/to/cacets/java" -file cert.cer`

If you can't do all the above steps, then you have no options but to write your own trust manager.

Something like [this](https://dzone.com/articles/how-setup-custom). You can search with how to implement own trust manager that would give ample examples.